# Uploading own areas 'videos' on Google Earth Street View?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-street-view

In Google Earth you can drop a human icon to view a kind of video view of popular places. I guess these are basically converted from a video taken of the place.

If Google allows anyone besides itself to contribute content, like making a video of my own street and somehow make it available on Google Earth, then where can I read guidelines about how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are describing [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/streetview/).

It also looks like you can contribute to it:

> Street View, by Google Maps, is a virtual representation of our
>   surroundings on Google Maps, consisting of millions of panoramic
>   images. Street View’s content comes from two sources - Google and
>   **contributors**.

The bolding above is mine.

From there it is a single click to get to the [Capture and publish your own Street View](https://www.google.com/streetview/contributors/) page.

Comment: Once published, will it appear in Google Earth?

Comment: I assume so. If you try it and it appears not to then whether it should is a new question that you could ask.