# Street view points are not visible in Google Earth app

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-street-view

I published a panorama image of my home in Google Street View app. But when I went to Google Earth app, and went to my location, it didn't show any street view points/circles. However there are a few other circles around the town uploaded by others. So why didn't mine work?

I asked initials of this question in a separate [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335989/uploading-own-areas-videos-on-google-earth-street). I followed the steps from there, but it's not listed in Earth app.

[image]

What can be wrong?

Comment: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7662671?hl=en&ref_topic=6275604 can take 48 hours (or longer) to reprocess your panorama image

Comment: @Mapperz it's been 48+ hours. Tried 2-3 shots. All are not shown yet.